# Can a student be admitted to masters programme even if his/her English level is lower than the minimum requirements?

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, toefl, language-exams

Recently, I just won a scholarship from my government for pursuing a master's degree in some Canadian universities. I checked the minimum requirements for the English level and I noticed that almost all of them are asking for at least an overall score of 93 points or 100 on the toefl ibt examination (6.5 for IELTS but only 2 or 3 are asking for this last exam).

I recently received my score from ETS and I got 85 points in overall (26 points on the writing section as my strongest point). Although I know I am still missing a few more points, I have published one paper on the IEEE computer society, I have won 3 scholarships for continuing my education (70% scholarship in my home university, 100% scholarship for doing a summer internship in Canada and 100% scholarship for studying 6 months in Sweden), and I worked as a full time employee during my last semester as a web developer and programmer.

My bachelor is Computer Systems and IT. I am trying to pursue a MCs degree in Computer Science oriented towards data mining and cloud computing. The universities I am interested are McMaster, Dalhousie, University of Alberta, UBC and Waterloo.

Despite the fact that I don't have the "minimum English requirement", should you recommend me to retake and work on my English skills or should I try to apply for any of these universities?

All comments, suggestions and proposals are welcome :)

Comment: The only ones who can tell you are the admission officers at these universities. You have a good position, as you are providing your own funding; but it is impossible for us to know.

Comment: While the linked question is not *exactly* a duplicate (close to minimum vs below minimum), the answers address your case as well.